# Method works in Visual Studio but not from exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a really wierd problem with my app. When i debug the application from visual studio it works perfectly but when i execute the exe file from the debug folder one of the methods does not work at all.

the weird thing is that it is just one method everything else in the application works

i read up on similar types of problems and most articles go in the direction of the configuration manager where the setting for platform is set to 'anyCPU' i changed the platform to x64 because my development machine has a 64 bit OS but i still get the same problem occuring..

this problem has me stumped for the last couple hours....

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Could you show some Code? (the method etc.)

Comment: ... and some error messages .. ?

Comment: It is impossible to answer like this. You should tell us specificts: What does your method do? I guess its not 'Hello world' that is not working. Any specifics with files, authorization, backend connections or stuff like that? Please post some code of the method that is not working.

Comment: Is this similar to your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262551/what-is-the-difference-between-running-in-vs-2010-and-running-a-builded-exe

Comment: well i cant show you the code but let me explain what it does.
it basically calls a method from a webservice and once it retrieves the data from the webservice it merges it with a dataset. its not very complicated.... it works perfectly when i debug in VS

Comment: the webservice exist in your solution or is a external webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that while debugging thru Visual studio u r not checking any properties manually(at run time)? I mean by putting some breakpoint and then traverse thru the property tree of the object. Because that can result in intializing some stuff which can lead to different execution path. I am saying this from my personal experience, as i was debugging and checked some properties at run time, which was resulting in desired result.

Comment: I am 100% sure that i havent made changes to the code or project properties while debugging.

Comment: I assume that by saying that "you have not made change to the object's properties", you mean u r not checking the properties,  manually, of any object at run time.

Comment: @Yugz: you do not need to make changes to the code. The debugger will evaluate properties in background for you, depending where you have your breakpoints and what watches you have defined. If your property getters have any side effects, these can influence program behavior

Comment: @Yugz: Exactly. that is what i meant. Thanks Marek for making the point clearer.

Comment: @Yugz: btw you can try by putting some logging. Like in the under scanner method, or in the code, that is responsible for calling that particular method. hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

delete all .dll and .exe file in your solution directory(those which are solution's project output) and then rebuild all project

Comment: ic,i had such a problem and solved by clearing all dll ummm,can you show that method

Comment: the webservice exist in your solution or is a external webservice?if your refferenced web service from ur solution when you run from Visual studio web service automatically will be hosted,and the othe r application can consume it,but when u running just exe you should be sure taht web service is hosted,so let me no is it in your solution or is a external webservice!

Comment: The Webservice is a separate solution but i have it hosted on my local machine

Comment: so its always accessible,isnt it

Comment: While making exe, you have keep the configuration in Release mode and build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with webservices there could be the problem, that the answer from the server is to slow. while debugging the program "runs slower" and the answer has many time. Without debugging programm runs fast and you have the problem of the answer not beeing there when you need it.

I've had this kind of problem one time and too needed a long time to get the point ;-)

Another solution could be a different security police in and out of VisualStudio (I'm not really sure but sometimes it seems like Programs have more rights while debugging (at least on my PC)).

Comment: I moved the call to the webservice to the form load and it works fine so i know for sure that its not a webservice problem.... i but when i place it back into the correct method it doesn't seem to work.... this thing is really frustrating is there some sort of setting in VS that makes the app run differently while in debugging mode?

Comment: Couldn't you show some code? We don't need the called adress etc, only the code...

Comment: well i got the exe to work properly but i'm not happy with the way i got it to work. there was a condition that had to met where a it checks if the form is visible and if another form was not visible. i just commented this out and it works from the exe now.... 

but its still not the solution because in debug the condition is false which is correct but in the exe the condition is true which is wrong ....  when i do figure out exactly what is wrong i will  post an update