# Subroutine works in Visual Studio but not from the .exe file

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, console-application, interop

I am having an issue similar to the user in this post [Method Works In Visual Studio But Not From exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262465/method-works-in-visual-studio-but-not-from-exe). However, the solution arrived at in this post is not going to work for me so I need some more suggestions from the community to see how I can overcome this.

I've spent a couple of days coding a program that works exactly how I want it to in Visual Studio but then when I build the solution and run it from the .exe file, a part of the program is not working.

The part of the program is this below. It types a lower case "d" if the user's Caps Lock key is currently on or it will type a "D" if Caps Lock is currently turned off.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module NavigateToTopOfDemographicsScreenModule

    Sub NavigateToTopOfDemographicsScreen()

        If System.Windows.Forms.Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) Then
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("d{Enter}")
        Else
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("D{Enter}")
        End If

        Thread.Sleep(1000)

    End Sub

End Module
```

This is a .NET Framework Console Application. I have it running as a Windows Form Application so that the Console Window doesn't show to the user when it is running.

I'm using this part of the program to send keystrokes to another program to ensure the program is on the right screen before screen scraping.

Again, the program will work when I press the "Run" button from Visual Studio but then when I build the solution and try and run it from the .exe file, this part of the program is not working.

The assemblies I'm using for this project are listed below if this might help.

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Core.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Deployment.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Drawing.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Windows.Forms.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So for now, this solution seems to be working: [Sendkeys not working on UAC](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b4d17ca2-2196-4db4-becd-fab24acc1bd6/sendkeys-not-working-on-uac?forum=vbgeneral). I found it on the MSDN website.

To get to the point, what I did was open my solution's folder and found a file called **App.Config**.

I opened this file in Notepad and added the below code to force my SendKeys.Wait method to use the newer version of the method as the user alludes to in his article on MSDN.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>
</appSettings>
```

After I did that, I ran the program from the executable file and it now seems to be working consistently as it did when I ran it from Visual Studio 2017. I will update this post if I have any further issues.

Below is what the user wrote on the MSDN website that seems to have helped me.

> If your application relies on consistent behavior regardless of the operating system, you can force the SendKeys class to use the new implementation by adding the following application setting to your app.config file.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>
</appSettings>
```

> To force the SendKeys class to use the previous implementation, use the value "JournalHook" instead.

Thank you!

Mark S.